# Using onClick function on a styled-components button doesn't change state until the second click (added sandbox URL)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, styled-components, use-state

**NOTE** : I have changed the sandbox link to the working code with some notes to what I had before that wasn't working correctly!

I'm still wondering if the code on the bottom is redundant though.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/sharp-satoshi-pgj5f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Alright this time I've added a URL to a sandbox with the basic idea of what is going on.

I have a styled-components JS file with a Button that I am trying to toggle the background color for onClick by passing prop values for the color, and to have a boolean attached so that I can later add API data to display based on the **true** or **false** status.

**Currently with how it is coded, the first click always prints the initial false state, instead of immediately switching to true**

Also, in my original code, I have a button for DAY, WEEK, MONTH to toggle a graph showing data over those time frames if their respective button returns **true**:

```
  <ButtonContainer>     
    
    <Button onClick={onClickDay} background={buttonColorDay} color={colorDay}>Day</Button>
    <Button onClick={onClickWeek} background={buttonColorWeek} color={colorWeek}>Week</Button>
    <Button onClick={onClickMonth} background={buttonColorMonth} color={colorMonth}>Month</Button>

  </ButtonContainer>
```

The top right of the image is what I'm trying to emulate:
[image]

Each of those buttons has its own set of 3 useStates and its own onClick just like the single button in the sandbox. Is that redundant or ok?

```
  const [clickedDay, setClickedDay] = useState(false);
  const [clickedWeek, setClickedWeek] = useState(false);
  const [clickedMonth, setClickedMonth] = useState(false);
  const [buttonColorDay, setButtonColorDay] = useState('lightgray');
  const [buttonColorWeek, setButtonColorWeek] = useState('lightgray');
  const [buttonColorMonth, setButtonColorMonth] = useState('lightgray');
  const [colorDay, setColorDay] = useState('gray');
  const [colorWeek, setColorWeek] = useState('gray');
  const [colorMonth, setColorMonth] = useState('gray');

  const onClickDay = () => {
    ...
  }

  const onClickWeek = () => {
    ...
  }

  const onClickMonth = () => {
    ...
  }
```

For now, I'm not worried about having the other buttons change to **false** when one is changed to **true**, I just want the buttons to work correctly.

@__@

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(clickedDay);
  }, [clickedDay]);
```

All it seems it took was a useEffect...

Also printing inside of the useEffect prints the correct state, whereas printing after using a setter inside of the handler function prints the previous state it seems.